# How to backup hundreds of Salesforce files/schema to postgreSQL database using Talend?

Tags: postgresql, salesforce, backup, talend

I want to backup hundreds of schema/files from SalesforceDB to postgreSQL. The Salesforce schemas/files are under

Repository>Metadata>Salesforce>myDB>.

In the case of several schemas/ files need to backup, I use Designer to build the job:

SFfile1->tMap1->tPostgresqlOutput_1

| OnSubjobOK

SFfile2->tMap2->tPostgresqlOutput_2

| OnSubjobOK

SFfile3->tMap3->tPostgresqlOutput_3

...

But now I have hundreds of Salesforce files to be backup. Since the subjobs have the same structure, I guess there must be programatic way to do it, instead of manually building subjob one by one. NOW HOW?

Comment: Have you tried selecting Manual Query in a SF component and entering a query like SELECT * FROM SFFile1?  Then you should be able to add a tLoop component and use the loop index to query the other tables.  Similarly you should be able to set the PostGres output table with the same loop index.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried to do the job in the Talend Open Studio for Big Data (6.3.1) enviroment. Under Talend, I have not found the Manual Query in a SF component. Do you mean that I should do it in SF environment? I am pretty new to both SF and Talend, as I know that there is limitation in SF on how much data you can backup on a weekly base. However what I want to achieve is to do daily backup of huge amount of data (~50G) which will run out of my company's quota. Could you please clarify on where to implement your idea? Thanks!

Comment: In the SalesForce component check the box that says "Manual Query".  I use TOS for DI so it may be different.

Comment: Could you point me to an example? Or even better, what do you do with my case? Thank you so much!

Comment: The Talend documentation at https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tSalesforceInput has an example of a manual SOQL query.

Once you have the manual query going to put a tLoop component in the job and make the query something like "SELECT * FROM SFile" + ((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION"))", hit ctrl+spacebar to get the proper syntax for the loop counter.